# onWillAccept: (data) and onAccept: (data) only has String as data

Tags: flutter, dart

I specified that the data of the Draggable is `final Map<FoodAttributes, bool>`.

However, when I then try to work with the data of the
Draggable once it's dropped on the DragTarget, the compiler tells me that `data` is of type `String?`

Here are the relevant code-snippets:

```
child: DragTarget<String>(
builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
return Container(
width: 300,
height: 300,
alignment: Alignment.center,
child: Image.asset('assets/images/Doggo3.png'),
);
},
onWillAccept: (data) {
return true;
},
onAccept: (data) {
           //data is of type String, even though in 
           //the draggable it is not specified as such.         
},
),
                
class FoodWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Image image;
  final Map<FoodAttributes, bool> foodAttribute;
  const FoodWidget(
      {super.key, required this.image, required this.foodAttribute});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable(
      data: foodAttribute,
      feedback:
          SizedBox(height: 90.0, width: 90.0, child: Center(child: image)),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 90.0,
        width: 90.0,
        child: Center(
          child: image,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your first line seems like the issue: `DragTarget<String>`  would need to be `DragTarget<Map<FoodAttributes, bool>>` to allow accepting those values. Then data will also be of that generic type. I'm not sure if it's a *must* but it would be better to also set the type of the `Draggable` to the same one your `DragTarget` uses.

Comment: @Dominic thank you Dominic! I forgot to change the Type... So I guess defining the data of the Draggable is just to make it more verbose for readability?

Comment: Indeed. As I've never used the Draggable widget I can't say for sure, but often explictiy is helpful. Did that resolve the issue or should I look into it further?